# Account Branding - Create Custom Email Settings API

Tags: onelogin

Has anyone used OneLogin API to Create Custom Email settings with Office365?

We are trying to change the FROM Email Address used on Forgot Password request and unable to get it working with Office365.

Appreciate any help you can provide

Thanks!
Matt

Answer (score 0):

OneLogin doesn't yet support Custom Email Providers. Although you can change the contents of Email.

I had same issue with OneLogin. I decided to send Email to users from SendGrid with OneLogin Forget Password link in it.